# Create many Layers and data views with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, data, symbology, mxd, sql-view

This code I've created works for 1 (one) active layer and for 1 (one) field. I need to implement this code for many layers and fields in a open .mxd file.

I have 11 fields (years 2003 to 2015). I want to select some o of them (multivalue field) and after choose, generate the layers view to each field (year). I already did for 1 (one) field.  But get stuck to many layers.

The shapefiles are from the same region/place so the best way to view is the layout view (create more than 1 data view)

The process  is:

i. choose the table
ii. choose the years (multivalue field)
iii. generate N data views from the selected fields

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0]
lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\PercACH.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, lyrFile, True)
Tabela = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)   
Campo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
    lyr.symbology.valueField = Campo

arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"F:\TesteAgro.pdf")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()

del mxd, lyrFile
```

EDIT:

What`s the best way to create many layers and data view for every year selected?

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the question and state more clearly what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Alex, I put more information after the code

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I am still having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Alex, my apologies for not being so clear! I put and answer for Jason and edit my post with a print to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius,

I would agree with Alex that it's a little hard to understand exactly what you are doing, but maybe this will help solve your problem.  Essentially you make a list of all the years (this is hard coded, not a parameter), and then cycle through each year on the list...something along these lines...

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0]
lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\PercACH.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, lyrFile, True)

years = ['2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']

# Don't need parameters
# Tabela = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)   
# Campo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

for year in years:
    if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
        lyr.symbology.valueField = year

    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"F:\TesteAgro{0}.pdf".format(year))
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()

del mxd, lyrFile
```

Comment: Jason, sorry for not being so clear with my question. My apologies for Alex too. Your almost attend my needs. I want to do this steps with all 'years' fields and also create one new layer to the active mxd for each year. Is more clear?